# trying to add an xml file to app

Tags: xml, titanium, titanium-alloy

So i am makeing an app in Titanium alloy and i want the app to recognize an XML file i made. for example when i make a new JS file in my controller folder i need to add this code to the alloy.js file.

```
Alloy.createController("sub_board");
```

What is the code to add an xml file i created in my Views folder?

Comment: createView does not seem to be a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since the controller and the view have the same base name, you do the following

```
// create a controller
Alloy.createController("sub_board");
```

the get the view

```
//get the view for the controller sub_board.xml
Alloy.createController("sub_board").getView();
```

or

```
// in seperate variables
var controller = Alloy.createController("sub_board");;
var view controller.getView();
```